# How can we use The World Chess Championships to increase the interest in this site?

Tags: discussion

There was a *huge* jump in the number of visits to Sports.SE during the World Cup; could we discuss any ideas to attract visitors and enthusiasts to this site during the week leading up to this great rematch of East vs West, youth vs age, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Chess_Championship_2014#World_Chess_Championship).

Comment: Good question. I recall quite a bump in visits to chess.SE during last year's world championship (and these days the typical number of daily visits has already grown to be significantly greater than that increased traffic we got during Anand-Carlsen I). The upcoming match will likely see chess.SE's greatest traffic to date.

Comment: Thorough analysis of every game could do a lot for us. It doesn't have to be original, even quoting other sources ( and giving credit ) can do. People want to see detailed coverage of the game, so they can see all the nuances. If we can do that then things can get much better for Chess SE...

Answer (score 11):

We could post the critical position(s) from every played game in the match and ask questions on these positions and post answers on these questions. We can even have a specific tag called e.g. "World Championship 2014 Carlsen versus Anand" to tag these questions.

Comment: I have added the tag, and made question one. I would ask it anyway.